How can I make two different Inno Setup Component Lists and switch between them using radio buttons?
Let me elaborate: my goal is to have two radio buttons displayed on the Select Components page, above the actual Components list and the Types drop-down menu. I'll simplify these as radio buttons A and B.
The idea is that when radio button A is selected (by default), you get a list of components to choose from as usual, but when you select radio button B you get a different list of components to choose from.
I hope this question isn't dumb or uninformed. I just want to know if this can be done.

If I understand your intentions correctly, you basically want to allow user to selected between installation of two different products, each with its own setup types and components. It is possible, but it's a huge task. Inno Setup's types and components system does not allow it. You would have to give up on it, and build your own custom component selection system. Similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40892063/850848 + https://stackoverflow.com/q/57058764/850848 + https://stackoverflow.com/q/74619839/850848 + https://stackoverflow.com/q/37931971/850848 (not that they really help you)

More like two different versions of a single product, but yeah, basically summed it up. Thanks for responding.
